tricky triangle problem with golden ratio
I am trying to calculate and derive the heights of the gray triangles in order to calculate their areas.  According to Wolfram mathworld the red and green segments below

the red and green segments have their marked lengths but it provides no explanation for how these were derived.

My attempts to derive this length along with the height h were to mark the upper left angles to use the Law of Sines somewhere and draw in the colored lengths to try to set up a proportion with similar triangles but got stuck with those approaches.  Any help with an explanation is appreciated.

This seems to be essentially a re-post of your previous question. Note that re-posting is not the appropriate way to draw attention to a question (or circumvent closure). Rather, you can edit the original to improve its quality in hopes of garnering re-open votes; you can specifically ask for such votes here. Alternatively, you can offer a bounty on the question to attract attention. ... Good luck!

^I did, twice, and it was declined twice.  So I reposted it with the edits and the work I did and it got a lot of upvotes which means it should have been reopened in the first place.

Note that in the original diagram, by symmetry, $MP$ is perpendicular to $BC$, and $\lvert A_{1}M\rvert = \lvert MA_2\rvert = \frac{1}{2}$. Draw from $C_2$ the line perpendicular to $BC$, having it cross $BC$ at $N$. Then $\triangle BNC_2$ is a $30^{\circ}-60^{\circ}-90^{\circ}$ triangle, so
$$\lvert BN\rvert = \frac{\phi}{2} \;\to\; \lvert NA_2\rvert = 1 + \frac{\phi}{2}, \;\; \lvert NC_{2}\rvert = \frac{\sqrt{3}\phi}{2}$$
Also, $\triangle A_{2}MP \sim \triangle A_{2}NC_{2}$, so using side length ratios and that the Golden ratio is $\phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$, we get
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{\lvert MP\rvert}{\lvert MA_2\rvert} & = \frac{\lvert NC_2\rvert}{\lvert NA_2\rvert} \\
\frac{\lvert MP\rvert}{\frac{1}{2}} & = \frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}\phi}{2}}{1 + \frac{\phi}{2}} \\
\lvert MP\rvert & = \frac{\sqrt{3}\phi}{2(2 + \phi)} \\
& = \frac{\sqrt{3}\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)}{2\left(2 + \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)} \\
& = \frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(1 + \sqrt{5})}{5 + \sqrt{5}} \\
& = \frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(1 + \sqrt{5})(5 - \sqrt{5})}{(5 + \sqrt{5})(5 - \sqrt{5})} \\
& = \frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(5 - \sqrt{5} + 5\sqrt{5} - 5)}{25 - 5} \\
& = \frac{\sqrt{15}}{10}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
For $\lvert PA_2\rvert$, use the Pythagorean theorem with $\triangle A_{2}MP$ to get
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\lvert PA_2\rvert^2 & = \lvert MA_2\rvert^2 + \lvert MP\rvert^2 \\
\lvert PA_2\rvert & = \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} + \frac{15}{100}} \\
& = \sqrt{\frac{25 + 15}{100}} \\
& = \frac{\sqrt{10}}{5}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Thanks :-)  Do you know how to calculate h for the larger gray triangles?

@John You're welcome. Regarding calculating $h$ for the larger gray triangles, I first considered trying to confirm that $\lvert BP_1\rvert=\phi$, as your second diagram indicates. If so, then it's relatively simple to use similar triangle ratios to get $h$. However, since $\lvert BP_1\rvert=\phi$ would make $\triangle BA_{1}P_{1}$ isosceles, so $\measuredangle BA_{1}P_{1}=90^{\circ}-\frac{\alpha}{2}$, I determined that $\tan\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)=\frac{\phi-1}{\sqrt{3}(\phi+1)}$, but the double-tan angle formula gives me $\tan(\alpha)=\frac{\sqrt{3}\phi}{5\phi+1}$, which however ...

@John (cont.) doesn't quite match the actual value of $\tan(\alpha)=\frac{\sqrt{3}\phi}{3\phi+1}$. I might have made a mistake in my calculations, but I checked several times. Alternatively, another method, although it's not geometric as such, is to set up a co-ordinate system using the heights & lengths, then determine where the line segments $BB_1$ and $A_{1}C_{1}$ meet. I haven't tried this myself, but it should work. Note that since this is not really part of the question you asked here, I suggest if you're unable to get the result yourself, you should ask a new question about this.

@John There's also a way to determine your height $h$ using basic trigonometry and similar triangles. From $C_1$, draw a vertical line up to $BC$, with it crossing at $N_1$. Then from $BN_{1}C_{1}$ being a $30^{\circ}-60^{\circ}-90^{\circ}$ triangle, we get $\lvert BN_{1}\rvert=\frac{\phi+1}{2}$ and $\lvert N_{1}C_{1}\rvert=\frac{\sqrt{3}(\phi+1)}{2}$. Let the point where your vertical line with $h$ crosses $BC$ be $N_2$, with $\lvert BN_2\rvert=x$, so $\lvert N_{2}A_{1}\vert=\phi-x$. Also, draw a vertical line from $B_2$ up to $BC$. We then have similar triangles so we can calculate both ...

@John (cont.) $\frac{h}{x}$ and $\frac{h}{\phi-x}$. Dividing the second by the first gives $\frac{x}{\phi-x}$ from which you can calculate $x$, then get $h$ from the $\frac{h}{x}$ value. I haven't done the calculations, but they shouldn't be particularly long or difficult to do.

I'm guessing you meant draw a vertical from B$_1$ up to BC instead of B$_2$?

@John Yes, I meant $B_1$ instead of $B_2$. I'm sorry about that mistake.

Perfect.  I thought the similar triangle trick only worked with right triangles and the orange triangle isn't a right triangle.  Unless I need to use the horizontal length from Point B to the new vertical line from B$_1$, which would be $\frac{3}{2}\phi + 1$

(The similar triangles regarding $x$ and $\phi - x$).
